# Can we use Build definition created by TFS 2008 in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfsbuild

We have developed an application using TFS 2008, Also developed an Auto build project using TFS 2008 and it was successfully running in TFS 2008 Server.

Recently we have upgrade our TFS to TFS 2012 and I have inherited all the code to TFS 2012.

Now i would like to use the already existing build definitions in TFS 2012.
But if i try to queue the build it is asking for a Controller which I was not configured in TFS 2008. SO I cannot proceed further.

Any idea where we can build the solution without using the controller or Can we create a controller and bind it to already available agent(TFS 2008 agent).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a TFS 2012 build controller and build agent. They can both be on the same machine. You cannot use a TFS 2008 build server with a TFS 2012 server / controller.

Once you have a 2012 controller and agent, you can use the "upgrade template" to call your tfsbuild.proj file